# Blender 2.8 render contains bad stripes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Trying to render an image, only to find the result contains bad stripes, both in Eevee and in Cycles. What is going on here? The viewport render looks okay, though... [image: Eevee Render]

Blend file: [enter link description here](https://eezacque.home.xs4all.nl/bug.blend)

Comment: is it possible to share the .blend File?

Comment: Hmmm, I solved the problem by replacing the offending balloon, but forgot to save the problem file. I understand this makes it impossible for you to help, sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in Cloth and Subsurf being in the wrong order in the modifier stack: Cloth must come before the Subsurf. For some obscene reason, this doesn't show in the viewport, not even in the render preview in the viewport, but it does give  horrible results in the final render.